# Split Multiple Columns into multiple rows in file

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a requirement where I have 25 columns, and I have to generate a file from the database with the first line containing up to 12 columns, and the rest of the columns should appear on the next line.

In the database, the structure is like this

```
PrimaryKeyCol,Col1,col2,col3....col24
```

Now I have to generate the file from this table in below manner

```
Primarykeycol,Col1,col2....col12
PrimaryKeycol,Col13,col14...col24
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know, but if you write the 25-column set into a table with an id identity column, you should be able to then execute the below SQL Server T-SQL code to render it in the format you wish:

```
SELECT PrimaryKeyCol, Col1, Col2, ..., Col13
FROM (
   SELECT id, Primarykeycol, Col1, Col2, ..., Col12, NULL as Col13
   UNION ALL
   SELECT id, Primarykeycol, Col13 as Col1, Col14 as Col2, ..., Col25 as Col13) a
ORDER BY PrimaryKeyCol, id
```

Comment: the bigger concern with union is the data types of 13-25 must be the same as corresponding 1-12 or error...

Comment: Correct.  If there's anything other than all varchars, since this is going to file anyways it wouldn't hurt to CAST all columns as varchar's.